# Spring boot Basic Auth only with specific web service

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot basic auth to generate the x-auth-token.

My configure Method looks like this :

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http     
        .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)        
            .authorizeRequests()            
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
            .httpBasic();

        http.csrf().disable();        
    }

  @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }
```

I do also have the RestController , where API's are defined.

curl -v http://localhost:8080/mycustomapi/login -u username:password

curl -v http://localhost:8080/othercustomapi/login -u username:password

By using above combinations , I am able to generate the x-auth-token ,But I would like to have only one method/API which should generate the x-auth-token.

Not all the api's should generate the x-auth-token.